# dynamically evaluate an expression with eval() and substitute() in R

Tags: r, expression, eval, substitution

I would like to create an expression which I can dynamically change prior to evaluation.
For example, in the vector below, 'names_test', I would like to dynamically change the vector index.

In other words, I would like to change the value of 'n' in the expression 'dynamic_expression' so that I can return the nth index item in a given vector.

Here's some code to give context to my question:

```
#Test data:
names_test <- c("John", "Mary")
names_test[1] # [1] "John"

# Test expression:
dynamic_expression <- expression(names_test[n])
mode(dynamic_expression) # [1] "expression"

# Test cases:
# 1:
eval(dynamic_expression,list(n=1)) # [1] "John"

# 2:
substitute(dynamic_expression,list(n=1)) # dynamic_expression

# 3: 
eval(substitute(dynamic_expression,list(n=1))) # expression(names_test[n])
eval(substitute(dynamic_expression,list(n=1)),list(n=1)) # expression(names_test[n])

# 4:
do.call("substitute", list(dynamic_expression[[1]],env=list(n=1))) # names_test[1]
do.call("substitute", list(dynamic_expression[[1]],env=list(n=2))) # names_test[2]
do.call("substitute", list(dynamic_expression, env=list(n=1))) # expression(names_test[n])

# 5:
dynamic_expression[[1]] #names_test[n]
dynamic_expression #expression(names_test[n])
```

Question: Test case #1 appears to accomplish what I want, but my question is, why doesn't Test case #2 do the same? And also, if possible, how would I go about modifying Test case #2 to return "John"?

So I updated the Test Cases to explore the comments to my original post:
Test case #3 explores adding an eval() call, but it doesn't seem to resolve
the way I want it to.

Test case #4 works, but I don't understand why the `[[` index for dynamic_expresison is necessary, and what the enclosed '1' is referencing in
'dynamic_expression[[1]]' I guess an expression is actually some sort of list?

Test case #5 might show what is returned when the [[1]] index for the dynamic_expression is retained and excluded.

Any insight it is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is because `substitute` doesn't evaluate the expression

Comment: What @Hack-R said is right. `substitute` will not evaluate the expression and you can't pass in a expression as a variable; substitute does lazy evaluation on the first param. There's no way you can may `substitute` work like that. What exactly are you trying to accomplish that you can't do with the `eval()` method? The substitute could turn the expression into `names_text[1]` with `do.call("substitute", list(dynamic_expression[[1]],env=list(n=1)))` but you would still need to `eval()` that to get "John"

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick : your feedback was helpful.  I edited my post to explore some of your suggestsions.  I welcome any additional thought you might have.

Comment: Well, I think the problem now is that `expression()` is a bit of a misnomer. The `expression()` function really returns a collection of language "expressions". What you probably want is just `dynamic_expression <- quote(names_test[n])`. Which returns a class of "call" but that's one of the many "expression" types in R. If you didn't use `expression()`, you shouldn't need the `[[1]]` part. Check out additional details on the `?expression` help page if you have not done so already.

Comment: OK thanks for the explanation @MrFlick. I think quote() might work for my use case, as you say.  Cheers